# trying to filter subform based on contents of field on main form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've looked at a bunch of other posts, an nothing seems to get it.  This damned Access nomenclature always throws me.

I've got a main form, with a subform.  I want to be able to enter a string into a field on the main form, and have the subform filtered as follows:

```
[Title on Eligibility List] like ""*" & frmNewGeneralclassification_fill_in.!txtsearchstring & "*""
```

This is not a "link master and child" situation.  It's doing a LIKE match.

I've tried

```
me!frmNewGeneralclassification_fill_in.form.filter = "[Title on Eligibility List] like '*" & me!txtSearchString & "*'"
```

and

```
me.frmNewGeneralclassification_fill_in.form.filter = "[Title on Eligibility List] like '*" & me!txtSearchString & "*'"
```

(Filter is not an Autosense option, but if I type it in anyway, it capitalizes it.)

and I get "object required" error message.

One of those SHOULD work, but they're not.

and

```
frmJob_Title_Lookup.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT [Job Title to New Classification].[Title on Eligibility list], [Job Title to New Classification].Employer, [Job Title to New Classification].[New Classification in EE], [Job Title to New Classification].[New General Classification] FROM [Job Title to New Classification] WHERE ((([Job Title to New Classification].[New Classification in EE]) Is Not Null) AND (([Job Title to New Classification].[New General Classification]) Is Not Null)) and ([Title on Elibibility List] like '*" & frmNewGeneralclassification_fill_in.txtSearchString & "*'"
    frmJob_Title_Lookup.Form.Requery
```

and I get "Object Required" error message.

Any pointers?

Comment: Syntax Me.containername.Form.Filter = "criteria" works for me. Cannot replicate the issue. If you want to provide db for analysis, upload to fileshare site such as Box.com and post link.

Comment: You have two different names for subform: `frmNewGeneralclassification_fill_in` and `frmJob_Title_Lookup`. Which one is right? Make sure that you use control name here. Also this error may be not related to filtering at all. If you don't have error handlers in the code of subform, but have in the main form, it may show the error from subform. Try to comment all code in the subform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that referencing subforms is really confusing in Access. In this case, try not using 'me' and just fully reference what you need (and remember to turn on your filter):

[Screenshot of my form with subform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFXfF.jpg)

```
Private Sub txtSearch_AfterUpdate()
Dim strWhere As String
strWhere = ""


If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearch) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " ([ItemCode] like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' OR "
    strWhere = strWhere & " [ItemDescription] like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*') AND "
End If


'remove final AND
If strWhere <> "" Then
    strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 5)


    Forms!frmItemList.frmItemListItemsSF.Form.Filter = strWhere
    Forms!frmItemList.frmItemListItemsSF.Form.FilterOn = True
Else
    strWhere = "1=1" 'this is always true and forces the filter to clear
    Forms!frmItemList.frmItemListItemsSF.Form.Filter = strWhere
    Forms!frmItemList.frmItemListItemsSF.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I think I tried that too.  I did a lot of permutations.  I think the big bad catch was that it doesn't want to do a LIKE statement.  If you've been able to get a like statement to work, let me know.

Comment: I use 'Like' statements like this all the time - no problem in either queries or vba

Comment: can you post some code where you've used it to filter a subform from a main form?  I have it working where I'm filtering the form the code resides in, but not the subform.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include more code and a screenshot